# How to detect when a server startup is finished?

Tags: boot, startup

I can establish an SSH connection to a server before the kernel finishes startup:

```
...
Nov 19 08:48:39 myServer kernel: [   11.305033] aufs 3.16-20140908
Nov 19 08:48:39 myServer kernel: [   11.389463] Bridge firewalling registered
Nov 19 08:48:39 myServer kernel: [   11.410197] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (4753 buckets, 19012 max)
Nov 19 08:48:39 myServer kernel: [   11.477171] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Nov 19 08:48:39 myServer kernel: [   11.665557] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
>> I can already connect through SSH around here
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.346036] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2275]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.500609] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2301]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.527922] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2301]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.570338] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:docker[2275]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.601081] device vethbdfcd80 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.613296] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): vethbdfcd80: link is not ready
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.718809] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethbdfcd80: link becomes ready
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.725877] docker0: port 1(vethbdfcd80) entered forwarding state
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.732093] docker0: port 1(vethbdfcd80) entered forwarding state
Nov 19 08:48:42 myServer kernel: [   14.740035] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): docker0: link becomes ready
Nov 19 08:48:43 myServer kernel: [   15.488079] IPv6: eth0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::42:acff:fe11:1 detected!
Nov 19 08:48:57 myServer kernel: [   29.760031] docker0: port 1(vethbdfcd80) entered forwarding state
Nov 19 08:49:29 myServer kernel: [   61.596905] ...
Nov 19 08:49:44 myServer kernel: [   76.786652] ...
Nov 19 08:49:44 myServer kernel: [   76.805961] ...
Nov 19 08:49:44 myServer kernel: [   76.825477] ...
>> I want to execute something here when the server finished startup
```

How can I execute something at the end of the startup? I need to have everything configured/started at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use @reboot in your cron.

Edit your crontab

```
crontab -e
```

and add the following:

```
@reboot /path/to/your/program
```

This will execute when the crontab daemon starts up

Comment: Interesting about the @reboot. But this is too early. cron starts when the kernel is about 5-6% initialised. I need it to run after 100% complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own `systemd` service.
From [systemd.unit — Unit configuration](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

You need [`After`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=) or `Before` option:

> A space-separated list of unit names. Configures ordering dependencies
>   between units. If a unit foo.service contains a setting
>   Before=bar.service and both units are being started, bar.service's
>   start-up is delayed until foo.service is started up.

That means as soon as network (or whatever you want) is up `systemd` will start your service. I think this is what you want.

I have written a sample service for you (taking NetworkManager service as reference)

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH connection
Wants=network.target
After=network.target # as soon as network is up systemd will start your service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/script
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target # This will insure that your ssh connection is done before you see login screen
```

*This is **sample** service setup, you might want to read following resources before you deploy it*

More: [systemd.unit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) and [systemd.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html)